# Is it possible to get the binary (or hexadecimal) representation of a value stored as double precision in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, binary, hex, double

Is it possible to get the binary (or hexadecimal) representation of a value stored as double precision in a PostgreSQL database?

I already tried to use a cast to bit(64) (double precision is stored with a size of 8 bytes) but I get the following error:

```
SELECT (1.031::double precision)::bit(64)
>> ERROR:  cannot cast type double precision to bit

SELECT (1024::double precision)::bit(64)
>> ERROR:  cannot cast type double precision to bit
```

For integers it works :

```
select (1024::integer)::bit(32)
>> 00000000000000000000010000000000

select (-1024::integer)::bit(32)
>> 11111111111111111111110000000000

select (1024::bigint)::bit(64)
>> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000

select ((17179869184+8589934592)::bigint)::bit(64)
>> 0000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The official documentation doesn't seem to provide a way of doing it for double precision values over SQL queries.

However

```
SELECT -0::double precision AS minuszero, 0::double precision AS pluszero
```

gives in pgAdmin III the following result:

```
"minuszero";"pluszero"
-0;0
```

which seems to indicate that pgAdmin is aware of the difference between the 2 values returned by Postgres (which differs only by the sign bit of the binary representation (IEEE Standard 754) of 0 and -0).

Somehow I assume that pgAdmin gets internally the binary representation of the double precision value from the reply of the database, and shows it accordingly in a decimal representation on the screen.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: psql shows the same result

Comment: I would not expect any RDBMS to expose its internals like you are asking... especially not through SQL, which exists mostly to hide those internals from users and developers. Why do you need something like that?

Comment: In this case I was interested in the possibility to distinguish -0 and 0. Any usual mean of comparison results in both values being equal (which is the expected behavior according to the IEEE Standard 754). Yet they are internally different and shown to the user differently "0" vs "-0". Comparing the binary representation would provide a way of making the distinction programmatically.

Another thought: why can I convert a integer to binary but not a double? (if "SQL [...] exists mostly to hide those internals from users and developers")

Comment: I want to make clear that this question is **not** about comparing -0 and 0. Please don't answer about a way of comapring -0 to 0, this is not the topic here ;) The idea of converting from double precision to binary did originally come from this problematic, but I'm interested more generally in a way of getting the binary representation of **any** double precision value.

Comment: If you only want to distinguish `-0` from `0` but not really interested in the binary representation, just cast it to text: `SELECT (-0::double precision)::text` gives you `'-0'`

Comment: @pozs indeed this is how I solved my little initial problematic :) Yet I'm still interested in getting the binary representation (it works for integer already)

Comment: You cannot convert `int`s to its binary representation either. Its more like a logical conversion. See `select (-1::integer)::bit(1000)`

Comment: Well, looks like it's working: `select (-1024::integer)::bit(32)` (integer is stored as 4 bytes or 32 bits in pgSQL).
`-0` has however no significance for integer so the initial problem doesn't arise in the case of integers. But i can convert integers to binary with a given bit size.

Comment: Double precision being stored as 8 bytes (64 bits), I would expect being able to get this representation with `::bit(64)`.
The more I look into this, the more it looks like something that wasn't implemented (still don't know if it was intentional or just forgotten)

Comment: You might be able to get it using http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pageinspect.html

Comment: @Zertin: Are those 4 bytes big-endian or little-endian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Somehow I assume that pgAdmin gets internally the binary
>   representation of the double precision value from the reply of the
>   database, and shows it accordingly in a decimal representation on the
>   screen.

No, actually it doesn't grok binary at all. This `-0` and `0` are text representations that come verbatim from the server. If pgAdmin understood binary, it could be able to display the result of this SQL sequence:

```
DECLARE c BINARY CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR
  SELECT -0::double precision AS minuszero, 0::double precision AS pluszero;

FETCH 1 FROM c;
```

and in fact, it displays an empty string as output in each column.

The `psql` command line tool is also unable to deal with binary because it doesn't support null bytes in raw query results.

This is not a limitation of the C `libpq` library however, even with its simplest function `PQexec()`. Raw bytes could be obtained and displayed in hex with this code:

```
  PGresult* res = PQexec(conn, "DECLARE c BINARY CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR "
    "SELECT -0::double precision AS minuszero, 0::double precision AS pluszero;"
    "FETCH 1 FROM c");
  if (res && PQresultStatus(res)==PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
    for (int i=0; i<PQnfields(res); i++) {
      printf("column %s: ", PQfname(res, i));
      for (int j=0; j<PQfsize(res,0); j++)
        printf("%02x", ((unsigned char*)PQgetvalue(res, 0, i))[j]);
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
```

result:

> column minuszero: 8000000000000000
>   column pluszero: 0000000000000000

You can finally see this sign bit as the first (and only) bit set in the first column. It's in network byte order, MSB first, which is reversed compared to the disk representation for little endian architecture, as used in the x86 family.